# Silverstripe does not use custom template

Tags: php, templates, silverstripe

I am using Silverstripe and i am really confused. I created Holder and Page class and theirs .ss files.

**mysite/code/NewsPage.php**

```
class NewsPage extends Page {
    static $db = array('Date' => 'Date', 'Author' => 'Text');

    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $fields -> addFieldToTab('Root.Main', $dateField = new DateField('Date', 'Date'), 'Content');
        $dateField -> setConfig('showcalendar', true);      
        $fields -> addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new TextField('Author', 'Article author'), 'Content');        

        return $fields;
    }
}

class NewsPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {

        public function init() {
        parent::init();
    }
}
```

**mysite/code/NewsHolder.php**

```
class NewsHolder extends Page {
    static $allowed_children = array('NewsPage');   

}
class NewsHolder_Controller extends Page_Controller {

    public function NewsList() {        
        $holder = NewsHolder::get()->filter('ID', $this->ID);
        return ($holder) ? NewsPage::get()->filter('ParentID', $this->ID)->sort('Date DESC')->limit(3) : false;    
    }
}
```

**templates/Layout/NewsPage.ss**

```
<article>
    <h2>$Title</h2>
    <div class="content">
        $Content
    </div>
    <p class="author">
        $Author
    </p>
    <p class="info">
    $Date.Format("d.m.Y")
    </p>
</article>
```

**templates/Layout/NewsHolder.ss**

```
<% loop $NewsList %>    
 <article>
   <h2><a href="$Link">$Title</a></h2>
   <p class="demo">
     $Content.FirstParagraph ...
   </p>             
 </article>
<% end_loop %>
```

These classes is for articles and works fine. I copied these codes for GalleryPage and GalleryHolder which I want for pictures. The problem is that Silverstripe do not use GalleryHolder.ss but default Page.ss template.

I cannot figure out why. For NewsPage.ss and NewsHolder.ss it works fine, but exactly same code in another classes (GalleryPage and GalleryHolder) use default Page.ss. Code is the same, I just changed all NewsPage or NewsHolder strings to GalleryPage and GalleryHolder.

Edit : copied code for Gallery pages

**mysite/code/GalPage.php**

```
class GalPage extends Page {
    static $db = array('Date' => 'Date', 'Author' => 'Text');

    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $fields -> addFieldToTab('Root.Main', $dateField = new DateField('Date', 'Date'), 'Content');
        $dateField -> setConfig('showcalendar', true);      
        $fields -> addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new TextField('Author', 'Article author'), 'Content');        

        return $fields;
    }
}

class GalPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {

        public function init() {
        parent::init();
    }
}
```

**mysite/code/GalHolder.php**

```
<?php
class GalHolder extends Page {
    static $allowed_children = array('GalPage');    

}
class GalHolder_Controller extends Page_Controller {

    public function NewsssList() {      
        $holder = GalHolder::get()->filter('ID', $this->ID);
        return ($holder) ? GalPage::get()->filter('ParentID', $this->ID)->sort('Date DESC')->limit(3) : false;    
    }
}
```

**templates/Layout/GalPage.ss**

```
<article>
    <h2>$Title</h2>
    <div class="content">
        $Content
    </div>
    <p class="author">
        $Author
    </p>
    <p class="info">
    $Date.Format("d.m.Y")
    </p>
</article>
```

**templates/Layout/GalHolder.ss**

```
<% loop $NewsssList %>  
 <article>
   <h2><a href="$Link">$Title</a></h2>
   <p class="demo">
     $Content.FirstParagraph ...
   </p>             
 </article>
<% end_loop %>
```

Can you please give me some advice how to fix the problem ?

Comment: Have you called ?flush=all on the page?

Comment: If your problem is with GalleryPage and GalleryHolder post the code for those pages,  rather than News. Maybe we'll pick up something wrong.

Comment: Yes I called flush, I checked syntax, I have no idea why it is wrong. I updated code also for gallery files

Comment: I will test your code next time I'm on my computer and let you know if I find anything.

Comment: I have put your code in exactly as you have it and it works for me. I put the templates in `themes/[theme-name]/templates/Layout/`.

Comment: As 3dgoo said - have you placed the template files within the themes directory?  Also, sometimes manually clearing the cache (i.e. delete the files in silvestripe-cache folder) helps.

Comment: Prembo, it works !!! I just removed everything from silverstripe-cache folder and now it is fine ! Damn, these takes me hours of desperate looking for error, whereas there was no error in code. Thanks a lot ... how can I mark your answer as correct ?

Comment: I thank you too 3dgoo, this was a curios problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As 3dgoo said - have you placed the template files within the themes directory? Also, sometimes manually clearing the cache (i.e. delete the files in silvestripe-cache folder) helps.

Comment: deleting the files in silvestripe-cache folder works for me !

Answer (score 1):

Your folder 'layout' should be 'Layout' (case-sensitive).

Comment: sorry, it is Layout with 'L' ... I fixed it. So this is not a problem. Problem is still that holder for News works but for Gallery not

Comment: Where abouts is your template folder? If you're putting this in the root of your site it won't detect the templates. You either need to put it inside your mysite folder or create a theme.